# Mark pipeline status 'Completed' with optional stages

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have 3 steps YAML pipeline **Build (1)**, **Deploy To Development (2)** and **Deploy to Test (3)**.

**My needs are very basic:**

- a. When some code changes in `master`, pipelines triggers (*OK*)
- b. With this changes, **Build** and **Deploy To Development** stages automatically runs (*OK*)
- c. **Deploy to Test** stages waits until I approve (*OK*)

But I've facing a problem if I don't approve the **Stage (3)**, the pipeline never ends and always shows an in-progress icon. So whenever I check the Pipelines page, I saw all pipelines are running but actually is not.

Worse part is the whole pipeline falls in *Failed* status after two weeks.

**My question is:**

Is there any way to mark **Deploy to Test** stage as optional? The pipeline should be completed without this stage but optionally I want to able to execute this step manually.

---

[image: Azure DevOps - Multi Stage Pipelines Summary]

Comment: By the way originally I've created an issue on GitHub. But it seems no one from Microsoft answering these questions. Issue link: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/issues/344

Comment: I think is not possible, MS should improve the multi stage. Open also a question here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your issue, I think it is currently not supported in multi-stage yaml.

If you want to run a stage manually in yaml, you can only through creating `checks` for your `environments`. There are only two options for review: `Approve` or `Reject`. So when you don't want to deploy to this stage, the stage will remain in the `waiting` state, and will automatically reject until the approval timeout. Once deployed to the stage is rejected, the pipeline will show as failed, even if the previous stages were successfully deployed.

So just as Shayki said in the comment, the multi-stage needs to be improved, it should give the stage a more reasonable manual trigger. Here I created a feature request for your issue in our developercommunity forum. You can vote and comment [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/785741/mark-pipeline-status-completed-with-optional-stage.html) to improve its priority.

In addition,as a workaround ,you can deploy with release pipeline. You can create Release pipeline in Releases Page. Then you can add test stage and set `Manual only` trigger for it. So that the pipeline can be completed without this stage .

[image]

Comment: I've accepted your answer because as you've said there is no action to take yet. Also thanks for creating feature request. I'll be following this thread.